# Will the distance still be measured from the centre? ( During gravity measurements)

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I have read that to find the gravitational force between two objects, we need to have the distance between their centres. Now if i have an object whose centre is not on it’s body ( as in a ring ), will i still measure the distance between the centres of my objects or something else?I think that the distance must be measured from the surface,if not then it would give bad measurements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gravitational field of a spherical mass is the same as the gravitational field of a point mass at the centre of the sphere. This result is known as the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem), and it is why we measure distances to the centres of spherical objects like planets or stars.

However when the object is not a sphere then as a general rule its gravitational field will not be the same as a point mass at its centre (of mass). And you cannot simply use the equation:

$$ F =\frac{GMm}{r^2} $$

For non-spherical objects the calculation of the gravitational field can become quite complicated and messy. To take your example of a ring:

[image: Ring]

The gravitational force on a particle on the axis drawn is:

$$ F = -GMm \frac{x}{\left(x^2 + a^2\right)^{3/2}} $$

However, if you are a long way from the object, i.e. the distance from you to the object is many times the size of the object, then it is a good approximation to treat the object as a point mass. In that case you would indeed measure the distance between the centres of masses of the objects involved. For example suppose we take the ring mentioned above. If $x \gg a$ then we can write:

$$ x^2 + a^2 \approx x^2 $$

And in that case the equation becomes:

$$ F \approx -GMm \frac{x}{\left(x^2\right)^{3/2}} \approx \frac{GMm}{x^2} $$

Which is the same as for a spherical mass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. Can you please give me a taste of the method that is ‘ quite complicated and messy’ ?

Comment: @AaryanDewan: I've extended my answer to discuss the case of a ring, as you mention in your question. For the details see [this article](http://dev.physicslab.org/document.aspx?doctype=3&filename=universalgravitation_universalgravitationforces.xml) or Googling will find you other examples of the derivation.